# WinbioEnrollment returns 8009802C?

Tags: c#, windows-7, fingerprint, biometrics

i have developed a **FingerPrint Management Application** for **WBF in Windows 7**.

it works fine in windows 7.

But using windows 7 in VMWare it returns `8009802C`.

> 8009802C told The requested operation is not valid for the current
>   state of the session or the biometric unit.

So How to resolve this?

**note:
In VMWare,i am using Windows7 Home Basic.**

Comment: Probably VMware cannot communicate with your fingerprint reader. Check the device mappings in VMware.

Comment: @ Roger : i check the FP reader,it connected properly.my application open only after the FP reader initialized.it opened well,the return code throws only enrollment function call.